# Using exchange web services to get the required attendees of a calendaritem? c#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the required attendees of a meeting which I got using the exchange web service.  Any ideas? I think I need to use CalendarItemType, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
Here is my code so far:

```
        foreach (var wrk in Workers)
        {
            TimeWindow timeWindow = new TimeWindow(startDate, endDate);
            AvailabilityData requestedData = AvailabilityData.FreeBusy;
            List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
            attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo(wrk.EmailAddress));
            GetUserAvailabilityResults ares = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees, timeWindow, requestedData);
            foreach (AttendeeAvailability av in ares.AttendeesAvailability)
            {
                foreach (CalendarEvent ev in av.CalendarEvents)
                {
                    //get info from each calendarevent
                    //Possibly use CalendarItemType here?
                 }
             }
         }
```

Where Workers is a class I made with a list of names and corresponding email addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve the required attendees by binding to the appointment using [`Appointment.Bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.bind%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx):

```
foreach (CalendarEvent ev in av.CalendarEvents)
{
    var appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(ev.Details.StoreId));
    foreach (var requiredAttendee in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(requiredAttendee.Address);
    }
}
```

You may have to convert `CalendarEvent.Details.StoreId` to a different format before calling `Appointment.Bind` (I am not sure about this), so if the above code is not working you may try adding a call to [`ExchangeService.ConvertId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.convertid%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx):

```
foreach (CalendarEvent ev in av.CalendarEvents)
{
    var convertedId = (AlternateId) service.ConvertId(new AlternateId(IdFormat.HexEntryId, ev.Details.StoreId, "someemail@domain.com"), IdFormat.EwsId);

    var appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(convertedId.UniqueId));
    foreach (var requiredAttendee in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(requiredAttendee.Address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You but neither works.  The second way gives an error for Appointment.Bind because the parameter convertedId is in the form AlternateIdBase and it requests ItemId.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @Sam: I changed the code slightly to use ItemId in the call to Appointment.Bind.

Comment: Why new ItemId is needed at Appointment.Bind instead just using the ItemId I got from a FindAppointment method?

Comment: @FernandoTorres: Good question.  I don't know why Microsoft chose to do it this way.