# Exchange services to get list of attendees of a meeting (microsoft outlook) in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I need to use Exchange services to get list of attendees of a meeting (microsoft outlook) in C#. As a suggestion I came across the following link:-
Link- [Using exchange web services to get the required attendees of a calendaritem? c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915309/using-exchange-web-services-to-get-the-required-attendees-of-a-calendaritem-c-s)

Also I have came across the following link -
https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api

Apologies but I am a noob to C#. Kindly elucidate the whole process from the scratch.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: EWS is a way to go only if you use the Exchange Server as a backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more EWS and find a sample code in the MSDN library, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: sorry but I am a complete noob to the technology. Do you have any link that could help from the beginning like lets say, creating the project, adding the reference of DLL to it. Apologies but the above link didn't explained things to a complete noob like me :(. Any kind of help appreciated :)